# snowflake kafka connector "failed to parse AVRO record"

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, avro, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to setup the Snowflake Kafka Connector to ingest Avro but it puts the data into the wrong stage and fails to load the table it created.

I am running the following official docker compose confluent Kafka cluster with a small change to allow me to install the snowflake connector:

```yaml
---
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.3.0
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-server:7.3.0
    hostname: broker
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_LICENSE_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_BALANCER_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: broker:29092
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_REPORTER_TOPIC_REPLICAS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_CUSTOMER_ID: 'anonymous'

  schema-registry:
    image: confluentinc/cp-schema-registry:7.3.0
    hostname: schema-registry
    container_name: schema-registry
    depends_on:
      - broker
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
    environment:
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_HOST_NAME: schema-registry
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_KAFKASTORE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      SCHEMA_REGISTRY_LISTENERS: http://0.0.0.0:8081

  connect:
    image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.6.0-7.3.0
    hostname: connect
    container_name: connect
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: connect
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: http://schema-registry:8081
      # CLASSPATH required due to CC-2422
      CLASSPATH: /usr/share/java/monitoring-interceptors/monitoring-interceptors-7.3.0.jar
      CONNECT_PRODUCER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringProducerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_CONSUMER_INTERCEPTOR_CLASSES: "io.confluent.monitoring.clients.interceptor.MonitoringConsumerInterceptor"
      CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH: "/usr/share/java,/usr/share/confluent-hub-components,/home/appuser/shared"
      CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
    volumes:
      - .:/home/appuser/shared #host directory:container directory

  control-center:
    image: confluentinc/cp-enterprise-control-center:7.3.0
    hostname: control-center
    container_name: control-center
    depends_on:
      - broker
      - schema-registry
      - connect
      - ksqldb-server
    ports:
      - "9021:9021"
    environment:
      CONTROL_CENTER_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: 'broker:29092'
      CONTROL_CENTER_CONNECT_CONNECT-DEFAULT_CLUSTER: 'connect:8083'
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_URL: "http://ksqldb-server:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_KSQL_KSQLDB1_ADVERTISED_URL: "http://localhost:8088"
      CONTROL_CENTER_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL: "http://schema-registry:8081"
      CONTROL_CENTER_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_INTERNAL_TOPICS_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONTROL_CENTER_MONITORING_INTERCEPTOR_TOPIC_PARTITIONS: 1
      CONFLUENT_METRICS_TOPIC_REPLICATION: 1
      PORT: 9021
```

I then download the Snowflake Kafka Connector `snowflakeinc-snowflake-kafka-connector-1.8.2.zip` and extracted it into my laptops `pwd` such that it as picked up at the volume mount at `/home/appuser/shared` in the `connect` image.

My avro schema file `PageViews.avsc` contains:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "PageViews",
  "namespace": "com.ippontech.kafkatutorials",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "viewtime",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "userid",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "pageid",
      "type": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I registered the schema on the `pageviews` topic on Control Centre UI. When I `docker exec -it connect /bin/bash` I can curl the schema for the topic with:

```
[appuser@connect ~]$ curl -X GET http://schema-registry:8081/subjects/pageviews-value/versions/1
{"subject":"pageviews-value","version":1,"id":1,"schema":"{\"type\":\"record\",\"name\":\"PageViews\",\"namespace\":\"com.ntrs.dmg.demo\",\"fields\":[{\"name\":\"viewtime\",\"type\":\"long\"},{\"name\":\"userid\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"name\":\"pageid\",\"type\":\"string\"}]}"}
```

To send messages into the topic I am using the official [Java demo](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema_registry_onprem_tutorial.html#run-the-producer) modified to use my schema and generated PageView class:

```
package io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro;

import com.ntrs.dmg.demo.PageViews;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Properties;

public class ProducerExample {

    private static final String TOPIC = "pageviews";
    private static final Properties props = new Properties();
    private static String configFile;

    @SuppressWarnings("InfiniteLoopStatement")
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length < 1) {
          // Backwards compatibility, assume localhost
          props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
          props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
        } else {
          // Load properties from a local configuration file
          // Create the configuration file (e.g. at '$HOME/.confluent/java.config') with configuration parameters
          // to connect to your Kafka cluster, which can be on your local host, Confluent Cloud, or any other cluster.
          // Documentation at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java.html
          configFile = args[0];
          if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(configFile))) {
            throw new IOException(configFile + " not found.");
          } else {
            try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFile)) {
              props.load(inputStream);
            }
          }
        }

        props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
        props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroSerializer.class);

        try (KafkaProducer<String, PageViews> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props)) {

            for (long i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                long id = System.currentTimeMillis()+i;
                final PageViews payment = new PageViews(id, "userId"+id, "pageView"+id);
                final ProducerRecord<String, PageViews> record = new ProducerRecord<>(TOPIC, Long.valueOf(id).toString(), payment);
                producer.send(record);
                Thread.sleep(1000L);
            }

            producer.flush();
            System.out.printf("Successfully produced 10 messages to a topic called %s%n", TOPIC);

        } catch (final SerializationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

These messages can be successfully read by the following test consumer:

```java
package io.confluent.examples.clients.basicavro;

import com.ntrs.dmg.demo.PageViews;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer;
import io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class ConsumerExample {

    private static final String TOPIC = "pageviews";
    private static final Properties props = new Properties();
    private static String configFile;

    @SuppressWarnings("InfiniteLoopStatement")
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        if (args.length < 1) {
          // Backwards compatibility, assume localhost
          props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
          props.put(AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG, "http://localhost:8081");
        } else {
          // Load properties from a local configuration file
          // Create the configuration file (e.g. at '$HOME/.confluent/java.config') with configuration parameters
          // to connect to your Kafka cluster, which can be on your local host, Confluent Cloud, or any other cluster.
          // Documentation at https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/examples/clients/docs/java.html
          configFile = args[0];
          if (!Files.exists(Paths.get(configFile))) {
            throw new IOException(configFile + " not found.");
          } else {
            try (InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(configFile)) {
              props.load(inputStream);
            }
          }
        }

        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "test-PageViewss");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "true");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "1000");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, KafkaAvroDeserializer.class);
        props.put(KafkaAvroDeserializerConfig.SPECIFIC_AVRO_READER_CONFIG, true); 

        try (final KafkaConsumer<String, PageViews> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
            consumer.subscribe(Collections.singletonList(TOPIC));

            while (true) {
                final ConsumerRecords<String, PageViews> records = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
                for (final ConsumerRecord<String, PageViews> record : records) {
                    final String key = record.key();
                    final PageViews value = record.value();
                    System.out.printf("key = %s, value = %s%n", key, value);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a Snowflake Kafka Connect using the following settings that I input via the web UI:

```json
{
  "name": "SnowflakeSinkConnectorConnector_0",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.SnowflakeSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
    "value.converter": "com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeAvroConverter",
    "topics": "pageviews",
    "snowflake.url.name": "somewhere.snowflakecomputing.com:443",
    "snowflake.user.name": "BLAH@WHATEVER.WHEREEVer.COM",
    "snowflake.private.key": "-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY----- MIIFHDBOBgkqhkiG9w0BBQ0wQTApBgkqhkiG9w0BBQwwHAQICa5fb8rrBeUCAggA 
...
H/V8Skgc4g6l/mk8mrmVOg== -----END ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----",
    "snowflake.private.key.passphrase": "shared",
    "snowflake.database.name": "SANDBOX",
    "snowflake.schema.name": "SANDBOX",
    "snowflake.role.name": "kafka_connector_role_1",
    "snowflake.topic2table.map": "pageviews:pageviews4",
    "buffer.count.records": "1000",
    "buffer.size.bytes": "500000",
    "buffer.flush.time": "30",
    "value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://schema-registry:8081"
  }
}
```

Then send messages into the topic I get no configuration errors on the snowflake connector. If I go to `http://localhost:8083/connectors/SnowflakeSinkConnectorConnector_0/status` in my browser I get:

```
{"name":"SnowflakeSinkConnectorConnector_0","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"connect:8083"}],"type":"sink"}
```

Looking at the logs in docker desktop for the `connect` image I see logging such as:

```
[2022-11-25 19:54:46,414] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-compose-connect-group-2, groupId=compose-connect-group] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-25 19:54:46,526] ERROR 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] failed to parse AVRO record
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR]  at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeConverter)
[2022-11-25 19:54:46,785] INFO [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=compose-connect-group] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-25 19:54:47,097] INFO [Consumer clientId=consumer-compose-connect-group-3, groupId=compose-connect-group] Node -1 disconnected. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
[2022-11-25 19:54:48,374] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] put file: SnowflakeSinkConnectorConnector_0/pageviews4/0/10_key_1669406086547.gz to table stage: pageviews4 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1)
[2022-11-25 19:54:48,883] INFO 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] put file: SnowflakeSinkConnectorConnector_0/pageviews4/0/10_value_1669406088374.gz to table stage: pageviews4 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.internal.SnowflakeConnectionServiceV1)
[2022-11-25 19:54:49,323] ERROR 
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] failed to parse AVRO record
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR] Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
[SF_KAFKA_CONNECTOR]  at [Source: (sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]; error code: 50005 (com.snowflake.kafka.connector.records.SnowflakeConverter)
[2022-11-25 19:54:49,836] ERROR
```

It says that it is putting the message into the table stage. The documentation says that it uses a temporary stage setup for the pipe to ingest. So it appears that it is using the table stage as a "dead letter location" so that it skips messages that it cannot process.

Most importantly nothing gets ingested into the target table created by the snowflake Kafka connector. That is a table of two variant types:

```
SANDBOX>select * from PAGEVIEWS4;                                                                       
+-----------------+----------------+
| RECORD_METADATA | RECORD_CONTENT |
|-----------------+----------------|
+-----------------+----------------+
0 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 0.449s
```

What am I doing wrong and/or how can I find out why it is seeing a "<" somewhere given that I can query the schema registry correctly between the connect docker image and the schema registry docker registry?

Thanks!

Comment: "As JSON". [Look at the source code return value?](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-kafka-connector/blob/master/src/main/java/com/snowflake/kafka/connector/records/SnowflakeAvroConverter.java#L190). Also, why not use Confluent Python library that actually uses the Schema Registry? Then use their Avro Converter instead of Snowflakes?

Comment: If it was all working as advertised and putting data into the table it generated I wouldn't have noticed it was using JSON. Thanks for the pointer that it converts to JSON to do an import despite snowflake having an avro file import type. So it seems the file format isn't a misconfig on my part. I have added a paragraph at the end to say my true problem is that if dosen't work and dumps my avro data into the wrong location. As for which avro library I used I thought avro was avro it is simply some dummy data. I will try java using the same libs as the connector “just in case”.

Comment: Avro is Avro. I was referring to the Converters. I didn't realize Snowflake wrote their own, as Confluent's is more commonly used. Your `Unexpected character` error comes from the Schema Registry url you've configured